# how can i randomly print an element from a list in python

Tags: python, file, random

So far i have this, which prints out every word in my list, but i am trying to print only one word at random. Any suggestions?

```
def main():
    # open a file
    wordsf = open('words.txt', 'r')
    word=random.choice('wordsf')
    words_count=0
    for line in wordsf:
        word= line.rstrip('\n')
        print(word)
        words_count+=1      

    # close the file
    wordsf.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
def main():
    wordsf = open('words.txt', 'r')
    words = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in wordsf]
    wordsf.close()

    random_number = random.randint(0, len(words)-1)
    random_word = words[random_number]
    print random_word
```

This works well, but if the file wordsf is too huge, then I think you'll start to encounter memory issues, but I think this should do fine for most cases

Hope this helps.

Comment: this makes sense. i dont understand, though, why you have to use len()

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Python provides convenient functions such as `random.choice()` that can make this solution simpler.

Comment: @Greg, ive been trying to use random.choice, but it hasnt been working out. what do you suggest i change in my mini program?

Comment: @lm: Have you tried the solution offered in my answer to your question?

Comment: @lm, len(list) tells you the length of "list". random.randint(a, b) returns a random integer between a and b inclusive, hence the len(words)-1. You should check the help on random.randint. Type the following onto the Python interpreter: import random; help(random.randint)

Comment: `random_number = random.randint(0, len(words)-1); random_word = words[random_number]` should be written as `random_word = random.choice(words)`

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
print random.choice([x.rstrip() for x in open("words.txt")])
```

Note that this strips the `'\n'` from *every* line before choosing a random one; a better solution is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @Greg, `random.choice` does _not_ accept a generator argument (it wants an argument which supports `len`).  If it did (or if you used a listcomp instead of the genexp), your code would print a random _line_, not a random _word_ from each line, as the OP asks for.

Comment: @Alex: Quite right thanks, corrected the use of a generator. I interpreted the question as asking for a random word chosen from a list of words given as one word per line.

Comment: Never open a file without assigning it to a variable or you can't close it.

Comment: @None: That depends on your confidence in the Python reference-counting behaviour where the file will be closed when the last reference disappears. This, of course, is not necessarily true for all implementations of Python.

Comment: @Greg, you were right in your interpretation of the question!

Answer (score 1):

To print one random word per line, your loop could be:

```
for line in wordsf:
    word = random.choice(line.split())
    print(word)
```

If there are lines with nothing but whitespace, you also need to skip those:

```
for line in wordsf:
    if line.isspace(): continue
    word = random.choice(line.split())
    print(word)
```

The counting part you have seems to be correct, but unrelated to your question.

**Edit**: I see you meant something different in your Q (as other A's also intepreted): you want to choose a random *line* from the file, not a random word from each lines.  That being the case, the other A's are correct, but they take `O(N)` auxiliary memory for a file of `N` lines.  There's a nice algorithm due to Knuth to pick a random sample from a stream without knowing in advance how many items it has (unfortunately it requires generating `N` random numbers, so it's slower than the simpler one if you have enough memory for the latter... but it's still interesting to consider!-)...:

```
n = 0
word = None
for line in wordsf:
    n += 1
    if random.randrange(n) == 0:
        word = line
print(word.strip())
```

Basically, at each line `n`, we're picking it to replace the previous one (if any) with a probability of `1.0/n` -- so the first time probability 1 (certainty), the second time probability 0.5, and so on.  I'm doing the stripping only at the end as it would be a waste of effort to strip temporary choices that are later replaced; and I'm avoiding the division and floating point hassles by generating a random number with uniform probability between 0 and n-1 included (so the probability of that random number being 0 is `1/n`) -- minor issues, but since they don't make the code any less clear, we might as well take care of them;-).

Comment: this does work, but it doesnt choose one word out of the entire file...and yes, the counting part is to print out how many words there are in the file